# Magento 2 - Newsletter subscription issue

Tags: magento2

I use Martfury theme. When I subscribe to newsletter, it redirects me to /newsletter/subscriber/new/ and there is this message (JSON): {"success":true,"message":"Thank you for your subscription.","redirect":false}
Image:
[image]

It should show only notification and not redirect to that URL. In Martfury theme demo it works well.

Code:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your theme, please check the newsletter controller return. Debug execute function line by line.

controller path: module-newsletter/Controller/Subscriber/NewAction

Then you can check the below function:

```
/**
 * New subscription action
 *
 * @return Redirect
 */
public function execute()
{
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost() && $this->getRequest()->getPost('email')) {
        $email = (string)$this->getRequest()->getPost('email');

        try {
            $this->validateEmailFormat($email);
            $this->validateGuestSubscription();
            $this->validateEmailAvailable($email);

            $websiteId = (int)$this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
            /** @var Subscriber $subscriber */
            $subscriber = $this->_subscriberFactory->create()->loadBySubscriberEmail($email, $websiteId);
            if ($subscriber->getId()
                && (int)$subscriber->getSubscriberStatus() === Subscriber::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED) {
                throw new LocalizedException(
                    __('This email address is already subscribed.')
                );
            }

            $storeId = (int)$this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
            $currentCustomerId = $this->getCustomerId($email, $websiteId);

            $subscriber = $currentCustomerId
                ? $this->subscriptionManager->subscribeCustomer($currentCustomerId, $storeId)
                : $this->subscriptionManager->subscribe($email, $storeId);
            $message = $this->getSuccessMessage((int)$subscriber->getSubscriberStatus());
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage($message);
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addComplexErrorMessage(
                'localizedSubscriptionErrorMessage',
                ['message' => $e->getMessage()]
            );
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage($e, __('Something went wrong with the subscription.'));
        }
    }
    /** @var Redirect $redirect */
    $redirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
    // phpcs:ignore Magento2.Legacy.ObsoleteResponse
    $redirectUrl = $this->_redirect->getRedirectUrl();
    return $redirect->setUrl($redirectUrl);
}
```

Comment: could you please describe me how to debug it ? Thanks

Comment: First you need to find the exact controller, after that debug execute function definition, try to check values with print_r and var_dump and use die() function for return the values, Also you need to check magento log files.

Comment: I solved the issue. Wrong template was loading in block.